# How to Create Dynamic Media Queries with Styled-Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to use the following approach below to not cause memory overload:

```
 ${MediaXS} {
    font-size: 0.77rem;
  }
```

Instead of using this approach below, which causes memory problems because it is an array:

```
 $ {MediaXS`
    color: red
  `}
```

But I don't know the correct way to export to use with the first example, what should I do?

**MY CODE:**

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

export const MediaXS = css`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  }
`;

export const MediaSM = css`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  }
`;

export const MediaMD = css`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  }
`;

export const MediaLG = css`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  }
`;

export const MediaXL = css`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
// configure screen width thresholds
const ScreenSizes = {
  DESKTOP: 992,
  TABLET: 768,
  PHONE: 576
}

const sizes = {
  desktop: ScreenSizes.DESKTOP,
  tablet: ScreenSizes.TABLET,
  phone: ScreenSizes.PHONE
}

// iterate through sizes and create a media template
const media = 
 Object
   .keys(sizes)
   .reduce((acc, label) => {
      acc[label] = (...args) => css`
       @media (max-width: ${sizes[label] / 16}em) {
        ${css(...args)}
       }
      `
return acc
}, {});
// use media methods with styled-component instead of raw @media queries
const StyledContent = styled.div`
  width: 100%
   ${media.desktop`
     padding: 10px;
   `}
   ${media.tablet`
     padding: 15px;
     max-width: 700px;
   `}
   ${media.phone`
     padding: 20px;
     max-width: 900px;
   `}
`;

export class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledContent>
        { this.children }
      </StyledContent>
    );
  }
}
```

Credits to *Ross Bulat*, taken from this article:
https://medium.com/@rossbulat/creating-themes-in-react-with-styled-components-6fce744b4e54

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dinamics media with styled-componets of this form:

```
const tabletStartWidth = 600;
const desktopStartWidth = 768;
const extraLargeStartWidth = 1300;

const responsiveDesign = {
  tablet: `@media (min-width: ${tabletStartWidth}px) and (max-width: ${desktopStartWidth - 1}px)`,
  desktop: `@media (min-width: ${desktopStartWidth}px) and (max-width: ${extraLargeStartWidth - 1}px)`,
  extraLarge: `@media (min-width: ${extraLargeStartWidth}px)`,
};
```

and in the component e.g:

```
${responsiveDesign.desktop} {
    padding: 5px;
    justify-content: "center";
    text-align: center;
  }

  ${responsiveDesign.extraLarge} {
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

And it works for me.